# Split comma separated data into multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The data below pulls from another sheet in the same workbook. This data below will update over time and have more rows (so it is not static).

[image]

How can I "split" this data so each shipment ID has its own row?

For the first row, this would look like:

[image]

The implemented logic would need to work for each row in the first image which means row 2 (with Shipment IDs F,G,H,I) would be split into four separate rows. The logic would need to be dynamic to be able to split more rows as they are pulled in from the other sheet.

Ideally, I do not want to use a script.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
={A1:D1;INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(C2:C&"|"&D2:D&"|"&MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(ax,bx,IFNA(SPLIT(ax,",")&"|"&SPLIT(bx,","))))),"|",0,0),"SELECT Col3,Col4,Col1,Col2 Where Col3!=''"))}
```

- 

[image]

Comment: your row 2 sample data has 4 IDs and 5 counts shipped. Unsure how to deal with this scenario?!

Comment: Sorry that error is mine! Your formula works! What a genius. Thanks! :)

Comment: As a follow up, if I now after the name column (after column D), also have a cost price column, how would I amend your formula to also pull the cost price into the results? The cost price column would just be a simple single value e.g. 11.50 or 90.00 in each row.

Comment: you may try: `={A1:E1;INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(C2:C&"|"&D2:D&"|"&E2:E&"|"&MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(ax,bx,IFNA(SPLIT(ax,",")&"|"&SPLIT(bx,","))))),"|",0,0),"SELECT Col4,Col5,Col1,Col2,Col3 Where Col4<>''"))}`

Comment: I am not sure if this problem was persisting with the old version of the formula too (I applied this formula in multiple files) but the above doesn't seem to work on the data in this .csv (downloaded from the Google Sheets file):

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/82ecf6db29cf28b3c0af9af8beb0f43a20230227150356/7c6a73

Comment: the formula above is done for comma separated `,` values in ID & shipped while the csv file is using underscore `_` as the delimiter. change both the `split` functions to reflect underscore as the delimiter and it should work.

Comment: Ah yes! Sorry rookie mistake. The updated formula is working for all of the files I have used it in but it generates a "#VALUE! #VALUE!" error in one cell of one of the files. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SGg4rqp1IllgRrEDtnrMPnvaup_8N4MnquLv6g02b9E/edit?usp=sharing 

I know there are empty cells in the data but this is typical as this file is a copy of a document that is work in progress. Also, I know there's no delimiter in this data set but this can also be the case (delimiters are not always present). 


How I can amend the formula to avoid the error?

Comment: If there's no delimiters its easier to go with a simple `=filter(A:E,A:A<>"")` rather than the convoluted version used for delimiters.

Comment: You are absolutely right - the only thing is that this file follows a script process and I can't make exceptions. Essentially, the formulae and file structure has to be identical.

Answer (score 0):

if A and B column are independent use:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(ROW(x)&"×"&
 SPLIT(x, ",")))&"×"&FLATTEN(ROW(x)&"×"&SPLIT(OFFSET(x,,1), ",")&"×"&
 OFFSET(x,,2)&"×"&OFFSET(x,,3))), "×")), 
 "select Col2,Col4,Col5,Col6 
  where Col6 is not null 
    and Col1=Col3 
  order by Col2", ))
 (A11:INDEX(A:A, MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))))
```

[image]